# Complete classification of the groups for which converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

It is known that the converse of [Lagrange's Theorem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHzMmG44_SAhXKsY8KHetGAU4QFggpMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)&usg=AFQjCNF6g7Mtzd67rz_uZl6xKZ3u67LjnQ) isn't true in general. More precisely it is known that the following proposition:

> If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $m\mid n$ then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $\operatorname{order}(H)=m$.

isn't true for all finite groups $G$.

My questions are:

> - For which groups $G$ does the converse of Lagrange's Theorem (as stated above) hold? More precisely, if $G$ is a group for which the converse of Lagrange's Theorem as I mentioned above holds then what properties must $G$ satisfy?
> - If there is no complete classification of such $G$s then can someone give me references to works by other mathematicians where they try to give at least a partial classification of these $G$s?

**Please note that I am not interested in knowing a complete classification of the groups for which a partial converse holds ([Sylow's Theorems](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig9-_p54_SAhVGvY8KHRemASYQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSylow_theorems&usg=AFQjCNELM79MscTLDVgAhVTtiQyhWYBFdA) does the job in some sense). I want to know a complete classification of the groups for which the converse of Lagrange's Theorem as I mentioned above holds.**

Comment: In any finite Abelian group, the converse will hold!!

Comment: @R.Chinnapparaj: But if the converse of Lagrange's Theorem hold for a finite group $G$, must it be Abelian? Please read my question again.

Comment: As a first step, the group will be solvable by Hall's theorem.

Comment: @user170039 Every $p$-group by Sylow's thorem satisfies Lagrange's converse. I.e. it does not have to abelian.

Comment: @freakish And more generally, all nilpotent groups satisfy this, so the group is somewhere between nilpotent and solvable. There is a book with a name along those lines, so this might be covered in that, though I don't think I ever managed to track down a copy myself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Can you tell me the name of the book?

Comment: It is called just that: Between Nilpotent and Solvable. It has Bray listed as the author, though it seems to have different authors for each chapter. It has a chapter on CLT groups (i.e. the ones you are asking about), as I just saw on amazon

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: Ohh, and I just noticed that there is an old ('68) paper by Bray which shows that all supersolvable groups are CLT.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Such groups are called *Lagrangian*, or CLT-groups. They have been studied often in the literature. There is no complete classification, but many interesting criteria. Two (out of many) references are the following:

- H. G. Bray: *A note on CLT groups*, Pacific Journal of Mathematics 27 (1968), no. 2., 229-231.
- F. Barry, D. MacHale, A. N. She: *Some Supersolvability conditions
  for finite groups.*, Math. Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy 167 (1996), 163--177.

> **Definition:** A finite group $G$ is called *Lagrangian* if and only if for each positive divisor $d$ of $|G|$ there exists at least one subgroup $H\le G$ with $|H|=d$.

It is easy to see that every Lagrangian group is solvable, and conversely every supersolvable group is Lagrangian. The inclusions are strict. In fact, every group $G=A_4\times H$ with a group
$H$ of odd order is solvable, but not Lagrangian; and for any Lagrangian group $G$, the group $(A_4\times C_2)\times G$ is Lagrangian, but not supersolvable. 
The classical counterexample to Lagrange's Theorem is $A_4$.

For example, no group $S_n$ or $A_n$ with $n\ge 5$ is Lagrangian. This follows from the fact that $A_n$ and $S_n$ are not solvable for $n\ge 5$. There are some more interesting facts, which can be easily found in the literature. For example, we have:

> **Proposition:** If $(G:Z(G))<12$ for the index, then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

The group $A_4$ shows that the above result is best possible. We have $(A_4:Z(A_4))=12$.

In the paper of Barry et al. the following result is shown:

> **Proposition:** If $|[G,G]|<4$, then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

Again $A_4$ shows that this result is best possible.

> **Proposition:** If  $|G|$ is odd and $|[G,G]|<25$, then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

In fact, $[G_{75},G_{75}]\simeq C_5\times C_5$ has order $25$, so that
this result is best possible. Here $G_{75}$ denotes the unique non-abelian group of order $75$.

Denote the number of different conjugacy classes of $G$ by $k(G)$.

> **Proposition:** If $\frac{k(G)}{|G|}>\frac{1}{3}$, then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

Because of $\frac{k(A_4)}{|A_4|}=\frac{1}{3}$ the result is best possible.
It means that if the average size of a conjugacy class of $G$ is less than $3$,
then $G$ is Lagrangian.

> **Proposition:** If  $|G|$ is odd and $\frac{k(G)}{|G|}>\frac{11}{75}$, then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

In fact, $\frac{k(G_{75})}{|G_{75}|}=\frac{11}{75}$, so that the result is
best possible.

Finally, let us mention a result of Pinnock ($1998$), which is related to Burnside's $p^aq^b$-theorem on the solvability of groups of such order.

> **Proposition:** Let $G$ be a group of order $pq^b$ with primes $p,q$ satisfying $q\equiv 1 \bmod p$. Then $G$ is supersolvable, hence Lagrangian.

Comment: I have changed the formatting a bit (as you can see). But feel free to rollback it if you don't want this change.

Comment: On the contrary, it looks much better. Thank you!

Comment: Sir what this notation $|[G,G]|$ means

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi $|H|$ denotes the order of $H$. Then take $H=[G,G]$, the commutator subgroup.