# The inverse of J.Lagrange Theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning Lagrange's theorem and I understand this theorem but I want to know the inverse of that. If a group $G$ with $|G| = mn$ where $n,m$ are two integers, then will the group $G$ has two subgroups $G_1,G_2$ with the order of $G_1,G_2$ are $n$ and $m$? Especially, will the group $G$ has the cyclic groups with the order $n$ and $m$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Asking for cyclic subgroup  $G_1$ and $G_2$ is way too much (apply this to $n=|G|$, $m=1$ and you have proved that $G$ is cyclic, whatever might be the group $G$).

Even if we forget the 'cyclic' assumption on $G_1$ and $G_2$, it is not true. There is no subgroup of order $30$ inside $A_5$ (direct permutations over $5$ elements) for example.

To expand a little on the topic of "converse to Lagrange's theorem". The most general converse to Lagrange's theorem is the following. If some power of a prime number $q$ divides $|G|$ then there exists a subgroup of order $q$ inside $G$. This is basically the content of the **first Sylow's theorem**. When $q$ is a prime number, the theorem is known as **Cauchy's theorem** and has a much lighter proof than first Sylow's theorem.

Comment: A smaller example with $A_4$ and 6 exists.

Comment: If a prime p can divide the order of a group $G$, then $G$ will have a cyclic group with order p?

Comment: @R.Sherlock, yes.

Comment: @Clément Guérin Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to your question: there is a class of finite groups known as *CLT groups*, where CLT stands for *Converse Lagrange Theorem*:

$G$ is a *CLT group* if for each positive integer $d$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $d$.

These groups have been studied extensively. It turns out for example that all [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) groups are CLT, and all CLT groups are [solvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). See also one of the early [papers](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102983900) of Henry G. Bray, Pac. J. Math 27 (1968). All $p$-groups, or in general nilpotent groups, are supersolvable.