# If a group is of order $m$ and $n$ divides $m$, must the group contain an element of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group is of order $m$ and $n$ divides $m$, must the group contain an element of order $n$?

Say we have a group of order $120$. Must the group contain an element with order $12$? If not, are there any theorems that tell us what order elements of a group must contain?

Comment: No. For the simplest example, 120 divides 120, and the only time a group of that size has an element of order 120 is if the group is cyclic.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments:

If any prime $p$ divides the order of the group $|G|,$ then $G$ must have an element of order p. This is due to Cauchy's theorem. However, it is false if $p$ is not prime.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)

Counterexample: Consider the group $Z_2 \times Z_2\times Z_2 \times Z_2.$ Clearly 4 divides the order of the group. Does this group have any element of order $4$?

Answer (score 0):

No.  If so then every group  would be cyclic.  For $m\mid m$. (Granted that's probably not what you meant.)

If we ask, instead,  for $n\lt m$, the answer is still no.

An somewhat important example is $A_4$.  It doesn't have a subgroup of index two.  It's the smallest "non-Langrangian" group.

However, imho the best theorem to know of this flavor is Cauchy's theorem.  It guarantees an element of order every *prime* divisor of $n$.  My favorite proof is to use Sylow, to get a subgroup of order $p^l$.  Then take the cyclic subgroup generated by any non-identity element. Cyclic groups have cyclic subgroups of every order dividing the order of the group. (There's a more basic proof, I am told, but I don't know it.)

There's also Sylow and Hall.