If $G$ is a finite group, $d$ is a divisor of $|G|,$ then there exists a subgroup $H$ such that $|H| = d$
Is it true or not? the question doesn't mention whether G is abelian or cyclic. It just say it is a finite group
somebody told me it is false,but I cannot find a counter-example.
But,
for me I would say it is true
as By Lagrange Theorem, for any finite group G, any subgroup H<=G, |H| is always a divisor of |G|.
Therefore, if d is a divisor of G, then d should be the same as |H|(?)

Please edit to include your efforts.

I believe $A_4$ is a counterexample.

I assume this is a question from an intro course. Depending on how far along this course you are, there is nothing better than to look for small counterexamples, $A_4$ being the smallest such one.
An interesting question is why this statement shouldn't hold, i.e. how you should get the impression to look for counterexamples. Maybe you've seen Cauchy's Theorem or the first Sylow Theorem that are strong statements about the existence of certain subgrouups. Maybe that should give you the hint that existence of certain subgroups is something special and not something that "goes without saying".

The fact that $A\implies B$ does not generally imply that $B\implies A$.

No, you can build counter-example. This quetion can be related to Lagrange’s theorem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCcSZEL_3CQ&t=72

As mentioned above, this is false. But I just thought I'd mention that it is true when d is a power of a prime (i.e. $d=p^k$ for some prime $p$). This is a famous result known as the first Sylow Theorem. Also, the result is true when the group is cyclic, which is a consequence of what is generally referred to as the Fundamental Theorem of cyclic groups.

Sylow doesn't say this for every $k,$ does it? Been a long time, but I thought it only did it for maximal $k.$ Tht is, $p^k\mid n$ but not $p^{k=+1}.3 @DavidReed

It is, however, true for abelian groups. But, for a counter example, I bet there is no subgroup of $S_5$ of order $15.$ There is not one group (up to isomorphism) of order $15,$ the cyclic group, and it is definitely not in $S_5.$

More than you want to know at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h

@ThomasAndrews It is for every k, although the other sylow theorems focus on the maximal power. See here:
https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Abstract_Algebra%3A_Theory_and_Applications_(Judson)/15%3A_The_Sylow_Theorems/15.01%3A_The_Sylow_Theorems
